# Sumx and Relatedtable in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like display the Product Current Cost measure for each Store_id in each Store_city in a matrix table using Power BI.

Here is my DAX:

```
Product current cost (test) = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        'Product Lookup',
        'Product Lookup'[current_cost]
    ),
    RELATEDTABLE(
        'Store Lookup'
    )
)
```

Output:

[image: matrix table]

Field pane:

[image: column used]

The Product Lookup table does not have relationship with Store Lookup and Sales by store tables. Thus, I am using RELATEDTABLE function.

I am expecting the current cost (from Product Lookup table) value should not be the same for each store_city in each store_id.

Anything wrong in my DAX?

**Updated:**

Product Lookup:

[image: Product Lookup]

Store Lookup:

[image: Store Lookup]

Comment: what are columns present in Product Lookup and Store Lookup tables?

Comment: @AshokAnumula  I have updated for the Product Lookup and Store Lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive result by following measure

```
Product current cost (test) = 
    SUMX(
RELATEDTABLE('Store Lookup'), 'Product Lookup'[current_cost]
)
```

Comment: We need to specify the table if using SUMX. When I add the Product Lookup table then the DAX will be the same as mine.

Comment: @Azul There should be atleast one common column between two tables. Then only Relatedtable works

Comment: You are right. I cannot use Relatedtable in here.